# auto-delete fluxbox menu entries

Tags: shell-script, fluxbox

I want to delete fluxbox menu commands that are in the form of -

```
[exec] (foobar) {/usr/lib/xscreensaver/foobar -root}
```

and there are 50+ commands to be deleted. But, how do I do it please? I need a command that I can put into my menu generation script, which will auto-delete them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This works -

```
sed -i '\|\[exec[]]\s[(].*[)]\s[{]/usr/lib/xscreensaver/.*\s-root[}]|d' ~/.fluxbox/menu; sed -i '\|\[exec[]]\s[(].*[)]\s[{]\b\(xscreensaver\).*[}]|d' ~/.fluxbox/menu
```

Watch out for line wrapping, it is all one line.